# Hall effect current sensor offset removal using opamp

Tags: operational-amplifier, current-measurement

My hall effect sensor (WCS1700) outputs 2.5v at zero current, I need to remove this offset voltage, and also amplify output.

I utilized both the opamps of LM358, first stage (A) to amplify signal and second(B) stage opamp to remove offset voltage. Under simulation it works as expected but in real world etched pcb not working.

Side A opamp can amplify the signal successfully but B side isnt able to remove offset, basically I get same output as non-inverting(B side) voltage.

Please look my layouts and simulation result, kindly someone help I have very limited electronics knowhow.

https://ibb.co/dJ3VNg2

https://ibb.co/5v6VmPY

https://ibb.co/GPYMDS3

Comment: What are the power supplies of your op amp?  If you're trying to go to 0V with a single side power supply, that's often not a good idea for many op amps.  Also, can you include all the images in your question instead of linking out to them?

Comment: LM358 isn’t rail-to-rail.

Comment: @ScottSeidman the other images have 5v input to LM358, I am using mobile browser to post, and image url paste somehow didn't work.

Comment: @winny my input voltage is hovering around 2.5 +/-0.1 v for either side of opamp, do i really require rail to rail

Comment: If you want 2.5 V input = 0 V input, you need an opamp which is rail-to-rail on the output, or +- supply.

Comment: @winny can a rail-to-rail opamp handle final 10mV at output (B side) as my voltage are still very low after amplification.

Comment: Yes. Find one with rail-to-rail on the _output_.

Comment: @winny can you please recommend a few rail-to-rail opamps, which are easy to buy, not so expensive, also in dip-8 package then better. I am completely confused.

Comment: Product recommendations are off topic here, but Digikey has excellent search feature. A word of advice is to learn to solder SMD as THT are going away and all new and good components come in SMD only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're providing a single-sided supply to an LM358.

The [data sheet](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm358.pdf?ts=1693385706519) states

> 9.2.1 Design Requirements The supply voltage must be chosen such that it is
> \$>\$ application scales a signal of ±0.5 V to ±1.8 V. Setting the supply at ±12 V
> is sufficient to accommodate this application.

However, the Characterics on page 1 say

> Common-mode input voltage range includes
> ground, enabling direct sensing near ground

So, I think on the input range, we're OK (but close)

However, the output is a different story.  The tables (Table 6.5) show that for a 1 mA output, you can't get closer to the negative rail than 0.75 V nominal.

An LM358 can do what you want it to do if you provide a dual rail power scheme.  With your power scheme, you need to use an op amp that is rail-to-rail on both the input and output (you need to read the data sheet to make sure) -- but even then you may not get all the way to zero on the output, just within some tens of millivolts.

On every data sheet for every op amp, there will be information on what allowable inputs and outputs are for given power schemes.  FWIW, I think mistakes along these lines are one of the most frequent posts for op amp design issues here.  There are some hoops you need to jump through when going from ideal op amps to things you can actually buy.

Comment: thank you for detailed answer, Now i understand root of the problem,  but as my signal even post amplification stage remain approx 10mV,  I am doubtful using an opamp can work